# I have to do a project using old .net technologies, is VS2017 compatible with old technologies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, iis

Recently they told me that I have to do a project with .NET, which I define below the elements that I have to work with:

1. Database management system: Microsoft SQL Server 2008
2. Development framework: .NET Framework 4.0.
3. Development Interface (IDE): Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.
4. Programming language: Microsoft C Sharp (C #).
5. Language of object mapping: Entity Framework.
6. Brand language: ASP .NET
7. Application server: Internet Information Services 7 (IIS7).

My question is if I can work with Visual Studio 2017 using ASP .Net Core but can run on IIS 7 using the framework 4.0, and also work sqlserver with the latest version and that works on sqlserver 2008

Comment: Entity will create a a set of classes automatically in c# that maps to the SQL Server Tables.  The mapping is not backwards/forward compatible with different versions of SQL Server. So when you change versions of Server the mapping will need to be updated.  The executable will only work when same version of Net is installed on compiled PC and deployed PC unless you install by publishing and then using Setup folder created by the publish.  If you are using Visual Studio 2017, not sure why you are using framework 4.0. I would use latest installed Net then target Net 4.0 instead of using Net 4.0.

Comment: What happens is that they are a requirement that they have given me, I can not change the version of the framework, it must be the v4.0.

Ok I understand that you can not work with the recent sqlserver I will use the specified one (2008), now if I want to work sqlserver 2008 with asp .net core, framework 4.0 using vs2017 will it be possible?

Or would I have to resign myself to working with visual studio 2010 using asp .net (not core)?

Comment: I don't think VS 2017 will work with ONLY older version of Net Installed.  You need to change Project settings to Target Net 4.0 and have VS 2017 with latest Net installed.

Comment: Ok, in short, it would be better to work with the requirements previously established to avoid possible errors at the time of implementation of the system, really what I did not want is to install these elements, since I have on my pc, vs2017 with the latest versions of .net framework and I wanted to work with asp .net core, but I see that I'm going to have to work with asp.net and install sql server 2008. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is backwards compatible so if You have SSMS 2017 installed it can connected to SQL Server 2008. So Net will use the SSMS Drivers (which will be compatible) from 2017 and you can can have a connection string to a SQL Server instance using 2008.  If you are on one PC you can have two instances of the Server.

Comment: @jdweng Your answer is excellent and I attack you for the time invested, I will consider the options, thanks

Comment: .NET Framework 4.0 is EOL, so that's a red flag. SQL Server 2008 (R2 or not) reaches EOL on July 9, 2019, which is another red flag. Microsoft has its compatibility page here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs Overall you should stick to VS2010 if you really want to ensure compatibility.

Comment: @Lex Li Can you explain to me what it means that .NET Framework 4 is EOL.

Comment: I am not surprised that you never read posts like https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/17455/lifecycle-faq-net-framework Microsoft didn't make it very well known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question for compatibility requirement is if you want to use SQL Client Class or use Entity.  The mdf file format for 2008 is forward compatible.  New version of SQL Server added enhancements without loosing compatibility.  So SQL Client class has no issues.   Entity is much faster interface but I've seen a lot of compatibility issues.  Some where people updated the database and then didn't update the Entity Modes that c# was using.  Other cases where version of Net and SQL Server changed and the code wasn't recompiled to use new libraries and drivers.  It appears the Net Library versions and the SQL Drivers are not backward/forward compatible.

Comment: thanks for the information, to avoid all the compatibility problems that may exist, I have decided to work with VS2010 and SQLServer 2008

Comment: I will mark the question as resolved to close the problem